# Why doesn't my ImprovedBubbleSort method work?

Tags: java

This is my java code for array exercises at my school
and I was wondering why even though everything here works when I try to use the ImprovisedBubbleSort method my program stops functioning

```
 public static void ImprovedBubbleSort(int [] array){
    boolean swap;
    int temp;
    int max;
    do {
      swap=false;
      max=1;
      for (int i=0;i<array.length-max;i++){
        if (array[i]>array[i+1]){
          temp=array[i];
          array[i]=array[i+1];
          array[i+1]=temp;
          swap=true;
        }
        max++;
      }
    }while (swap=true);
    System.out.println("The numbers you entered in order are: ");
    for (int j=0;j<10;j++){
      System.out.println(array[j]);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: `while (swap=true)` should just be `while (swap)`. Single `=` is assignment, so the loop will always continue infinitely.

Comment: Adding to @bcsb1001 you don't need to check with `swap==true` you can just leave it at `swap` to check if it's true.

Comment: It worked but then my for loop only went through once do you know why?

Comment: You're running through it once (one loop) from left to right swapping but if there's an instance in which the logic considers array[i] < array[i+1] then the if statements no longer executed. See [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/bubble-sort-in-java) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to realize that if you're using a single loop like in your example with that if statement you can find an instance of position 0 and 1 where it is sorted but the rest of the array may not be sorted. This will cause the if statement to not activate.

You can alleviate this problem by doing something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {


    int test[] = {7,1,9,1,5,6};
    bubbleSort(test);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
    }

    static void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {  
        int n = arr.length;  
        int temp = 0;  
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++){  
            for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){  
                if(arr[j-1] > arr[j]){  
                    //swap elements  
                    temp = arr[j-1];  
                    arr[j-1] = arr[j];  
                    arr[j] = temp;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }
}
```

See [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/bubble-sort-in-java) example.